# Android setVisibility View.INVISIBLE and View.GONE aren't working

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to figure out why View.INVISIBLE and View.GONE in my android app aren't working.

I believe my logic is accounting correctly for !=null values but perhaps it's not?

Below is my syntax. My goal is this, if theirs information I want to display that information to the user. If facebook, twitter, yelp etc... aren't displaying information then I don't want a large white space to be presented to my user (it's not pleasing to the eye). My question is, what am I doing wrong, how can I fix this? My syntax is below. Thanks

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    allTheshipInfo infoHolder;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_dealership_information, parent, false);

        infoHolder = new allTheshipInfo();
        infoHolder.facebook = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.theFacebook);
        infoHolder.twitter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.theTwitter);  
        infoHolder.youtube = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.theYoutube);
        infoHolder.googlePlus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.theGoogle_plus);
        infoHolder.yelp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.theYelp);

        convertView.setTag(infoHolder);

    } else {
        infoHolder = (allTheDealershipInfo) convertView.getTag();

    }

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = this.dataArray.getJSONObject(position);

        infoHolder.dealerships.setText(jsonObject.getString("business"));   
        infoHolder.state.setText(jsonObject.getString("state"));
        infoHolder.city.setText(jsonObject.getString("city"));
        infoHolder.phone.setText(jsonObject.getString("phone"));
        infoHolder.address.setText(jsonObject.getString("address"));
        infoHolder.zip.setText(jsonObject.getString("zip"));
        infoHolder.email.setText(jsonObject.getString("email"));
        infoHolder.website.setText(jsonObject.getString("website"));
        infoHolder.facebook.setText(jsonObject.getString("facebook"));
        infoHolder.twitter.setText(jsonObject.getString("twitter"));

        infoHolder.youtube.setText(jsonObject.getString("youtube"));
        infoHolder.googlePlus.setText(jsonObject.getString("google_plus"));
        infoHolder.yelp.setText(jsonObject.getString("yelp"));


                    if(facebook.isEmpty()){
            infoHolder.facebook.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Facebook Gone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            infoHolder.facebook.setText(facebook);
            infoHolder.facebook.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Facebook Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(twitter.isEmpty()){
            infoHolder.twitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Twitter Gone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            infoHolder.twitter.setText(twitter);
            infoHolder.twitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Twitter Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(youtube.isEmpty()){
            infoHolder.youtube.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(activity, "YouTube Gone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            infoHolder.youtube.setText(youtube);
            infoHolder.youtube.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(activity, "YouTube Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(googlePlus.isEmpty()){
            infoHolder.googlePlus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(activity, "GooglePlus Gone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            infoHolder.googlePlus.setText(googlePlus);
            infoHolder.googlePlus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(activity, "GooglePlus Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(yelp.isEmpty()){
            infoHolder.yelp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Yelp Gone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            infoHolder.yelp.setText(yelp);
            infoHolder.yelp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(activity, "GooglePlus Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Toast.makeText(activity, "Call " + jsonObject.getString("business"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(activity, "# " + jsonObject.getString("phone"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="@string/facebook"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:id="@+id/theFacebook"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="@string/twitter"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:id="@+id/theTwitter"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="@string/google_plus"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:id="@+id/theGoogle_plus"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="@string/yelp"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:id="@+id/theYelp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>
    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="@string/youtube"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:id="@+id/theYoutube"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>      

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: your setVisibility method should be outside if(convertView == null) body.

Comment: @moh.sukhni I changed a few things around. It's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are putting to much thing in the `else` clause. it should only contain `infoHolder = (allTheDealershipInfo) convertView.getTag();`

Comment: `} else if (infoHolder.facebook == null) {
            infoHolder.facebook.setVisibility(View.GONE);` does not make any sense. you cannot call `setVisibility` if you just tested that it is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to show/hide the textviews based on whether the related json data is available. 
As for your current code:

```
infoHolder.yelp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.theYelp);

if(infoHolder.yelp != null){
    ...
}
```

The if statement you declared is just checking whether the textview is null, it will never be null since its assigned a textview in the beginning. You should first determine whether the json data exists before deciding whether to show/hide the textview.

For example:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = this.dataArray.getJSONObject(position);
String yelpStr = jsonObject.optString("yelp");
if(yelpStr != null){
    infoHolder.yelp.setText(yelpStr);
    infoHolder.yelp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Yelp Here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    infoHolder.yelp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Yelp Gone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Also, I believe you misplaced a right curly brace, it should be right after infoHolder is retrieved using the tag:

```
if(convertView == null){
    ...
}else{
    infoHolder = (allTheDealershipInfo) convertView.getTag();
}
```

Make sure u end the if/else statement for assigning infoHolder properly so the textviews will be used in the rest of the code as intended.

Comment: thanks for the help. I appreciate it. I've updated my syntax above to what's working. I've marked this answer with the green check, which I believe indicates it's the correct answer. I tweeked the syntax a bit and changed `!=null` to `isEmpty()` method.  The only issue I'm having now is the Toast messages are appearing twice?

Comment: the getView method is called for every item on the listview, it returns the view for each item. That being said, each time your list loads or when scrolled, each item visible could return a Toast. If you really want to have debug messages, you can try using Log.d(label, message) instead and follow what happens in LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to do something like this (only example for facebook):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    allTheshipInfo infoHolder;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_dealership_information, parent, false);

        infoHolder = new allTheshipInfo();
        infoHolder.facebook = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.theFacebook);
        convertView.setTag(infoHolder);

    } else infoHolder = (allTheDealershipInfo) convertView.getTag();

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObject = this.dataArray.getJSONObject(position);
        if (jsonObject.getString("facebook") == null)
            infoHolder.facebook.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace(); }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I've changed my syntax above. Have a look, thanks for your help as well